# Make fullscreen API code work cross browser

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

On my page I have following code, which I use for making some object a full screen one

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fs-button').on('click', function(){
        var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
        if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } else {
            elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem is its working only in Chrome. Can you please give me cross browser version of this code? Cannot do this by myself because of poor JS knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. 
Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx

```js
    // Initiated by a user click on an element 

    function makeFullScreen(divObj) {
       //Use the specification method before using prefixed versions
      if (divObj.requestFullscreen) {
        divObj.requestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (divObj.msRequestFullscreen) {
        divObj.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (divObj.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        divObj.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
      else if (divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        divObj.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else {
        console.log("Fullscreen API is not supported");
      } 

    }
```

---

once after writing that function, you just need to call inside click event handler as..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fs-button').on('click', function(){
      var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
        //call that function to make it fullscreen.
        makeFullScreen( elem );
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea where should I past your code and how make it work at all. I give my code snippet for a reason - because I already found how make it work. By clicking button which have .fs-button class we make object with #fullscreen id fullscreen. All I need is to add to my code additional lines to make it work in all browsers. Yes, I totally do not know JS.

Comment: Thanks for a help!